# Pythonista core module

Tags: python, pythonista

I'm quite new to Pythonista and I’ve found the StaSh pip installer. I installed the module PyDictionary but for some reason whenever I try to import it, it gives me an error saying I haven't got a module called "core". I tried to pip install "core 1.0.1" but didn’t succeed, and I can't find the zip file for the "core 1.0.1" module on the PyPI or elsewhere online.

All it’s saying is:

```
from core import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "core"
```

Comment: Are you sure that `core` is the top level module name of whatever you installed? That name seems dangerously generic, so I'd expect it to be something more like `packagename.core`.

Comment: @Blckknght So I went digging and found a core.py file in the module’s package. I just can’t find where I need to put the file’s to actually be able to use them.

Comment: Is the import statement you see in the exception message part of your own code, or part of `PyDictionary/__init__.py` (if you can, edit the question to show the full traceback)? If it's part of your code, you probably want to be importing `PyDictionary` instead. If the error is in the `__init__.py`, then you're right that something's messed up with the package installation. Unfortunately, at that point I can't help you any more as I know nothing at all about pythonista.

Comment: @Blckknght It’s part of the package. I don’t think it is entirely messed up though because I managed to get the package running perfectly well in the console at one point; as soon as I tried to implement it into my code it messed up and now I can’t even get it working in the console. I’m sure it’s because of where the package is in my file directory but it won’t work when I put it in any of the ‘site-packages’ folders.

Comment: @Blckknght So I reinstalled the package and somehow everything seems to be working now. Not sure what made the difference but it’s fixed. Thanks anyway